# Error en composer

Tags: composer

Quiero crear un nuevo proyecto en Laravel y me tira este error composer, la verdad que no me deja ni tirar un composer-update.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si buscas en *Google*: `ssl connection reset by peer` tienes algo como: 'A connection reset by peer message means that the site you are connected to has reset the connection. This is usually caused by a high amount of traffic on the site, but may be caused by a server error as well.', es decir que el sitio de destino cerro la conexión por exceso de trafico o hay un error en el servidor. A priori, no es un error de tu Composer / proyecto y quizá funcione si lo intentas en otro momento...

Comment: Puede ser también que tengas configurado el paquete correspondiente por https en lugar de git. Pero como te dice @Orici es un tema de validación contra packagist. Revisa tu composer.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuve que eliminar todo por completo y volver a re-instalar todos los servicios. Al parecer en una actualizacion se daño el core de todo.

Answer (score 0):

El comando no es correcto, debe ir sin guión(-):

```
composer update
```

Aunque antes de todo comprueba la versión que tienes:

```
composer -v
```

Comment: No, esto no me deja.

Comment: Tendrás que instalarlo, composer install

Answer (score 0):

Necesitamos la última versión del lenguaje PHP: 7, ya que es un requisito del propio Laravel 5.5. Para instalar PHP 7 puedes seguir uno de los pasos que se explican en el Manual de PHP.

Para saber si tenemos PHP instalado, al menos en PHP 7. Tienes el comando:

```
php --version
```

Nos dirigimos a la carpeta de nuestro ordenador donde queremos instalar Laravel. Puede ser cualquier carpeta donde guardes tus proyectos. El comando para crear el proyecto depende de Composer. Es el siguiente:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel mi-proyecto-laravel
```

Opcionalmente podríamos también indicar la versión de Laravel que queremos instalar, por ejemplo:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel mi-proyecto-laravel 5.5.*
```

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver un error de conexión como lo indica el mensaje con la versión de PHP?

Comment: No es un problema de la version. Es un problema de paquetes de brew